# Dynamically import functions into an ES5 JS file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This might seem a little convoluted, so I apologize in advance if it does.
I'm attempting to create a build tool in Node.js for Chrome Extensions, so the final JS file has to be ES5 compliant.

I have separate JS files for each setting within the extension that export an object, the function within this object needs to be imported into the contentScript.js file and placed within it's own settings object.

I've put together a [basic screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEizp.png) that shows how this should flow, but I'm not sure of how to approach this issue. I've considered some type of string interpolation within the contentScript which Node would then replace, but that seems more of a workaround than a solution.

Say we have a folder called settings, within those settings are two JavaScript files, each with a different name, type, and function, they'd look like this.

```
// settingName1.js
module.exports = {
    name: 'Setting Name 1',
    type: 'switch',
    function: () => {
        console.log('Setting 1 initialized');
    }
}
```

Ideally, both of these files would have their respective functions imported into the contentScript, under a settings object, for example.

```
// contentScript.js
    // Settings Functions Go Here
    const settings = {
        settingName1: function() {
            console.log('Setting 1 initialized')
        },
        settingName2: function() {
            console.log('Setting 2 initialized')
        }
    }
});
```

Basically cutting/copying the function from the source setting file itself, and pasting it under a function (named using the file's name) within the contentScript's settings object.

Comment: If the files in questions are using `module.exports`, then why not just `require()` them in, grab the object they export and assign the function you want from the object they export onto the common settings object?  If you're looking for how to figure out  what property name to assign them to on the settings object, then it looks like you can use the exported `name` property to get that or derive the property  name from.  I don't understand what your question is beyond this.

Comment: Also, please embed your image directly into your post rather than only as an external link so it can more easily be seen and so that it won't disappear over time when it ages off imgur.com.

Comment: @jfriend00 Having a new account, I was unable to directly embed the image, I would have if I could.

Comment: I attempted to require it, but that always resulted in the final contentScript file trying to require it from Chrome, which returned a "require is not defined" error, seeing as browsers don't support that yet. So I need to import and compile that function into the file itself, baking it in, if you will.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what the final result you're trying to make is.  Can you show (pasted into your question and formatted as code) what the final resulting text file should look like?

Comment: @jfriend00 Of course. I knew this would be a rather convoluted question, I was hoping I could explain it in a way that made a bit more sense. I updated it with a bit of an example, though I'm not sure it's any better than the screenshot I included.

Comment: Not easy. Probably involves parsing contentScript files yourself to find what you need, then including the whole body into your master script embedded into its own scope so it has private scope that won't conflict with others.  Sounds messy.

Comment: That sounds absurdly painful. I was imagining Regex could be an option to parse out only the function, then merging them together in a string and appending it to the final file, I feel like that could work but it wouldn't be pretty.

Node doesn't actually need to understand or run any of this, just transfer it from a friendlier environment to one Chrome runs in a single script. It's like an advanced bundling method, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea for the generated file:

```
// header on the file
const capturedExports = [];

// insert this prologue before each inserted file
(function() {
// =============================
// insert settingName1.js here
module.exports = {
    name: 'Setting Name 1',
    type: 'switch',
    function: () => {
        console.log('Setting 1 initialized');
    }
}

// =============================

// insert this epilogue after each inserted file
})();
capturedExports.push(module.exports);


// insert this prologue before each inserted file
(function() {
    // =============================
// insert settingName2.js here
module.exports = {
    name: 'Setting Name 2',
    type: 'switch',
    function: () => {
        console.log('Setting 2 initialized');
    }
}
// =============================

// insert this epilogue after each inserted file
})();
capturedExports.push(module.exports);

// insert code that builds the settings object
const settings = {};
for (let exportItem of capturedExports) {
    let name = exportItem.name.replace(/\s/, "");
    name = name.slice(0, 1).toLowerCase() + name.slice(1);
    settings[name] = exportItem.function;
}
```

You do the following steps to output a new file that is collection of all the `settingNamex.js` files.

1. Create the new file.
2. Write a header to it with the `const capturedExports = [];` line and the start of the IIFE.
3. For each `settingNameX.js` file, write that file to it.
4. Then write the close of the IIFE and the `capturedExports.push(module.exports);` after it.  This will grab whatever the previous code assigned to `module.exports` and add it to the `caputuredExports` array.
5. Repeat this process for each `settingNameX.js` file.
6. Then, insert the code that builds the settings object from the `capturedExports` array.

Enclosing each inserted module in its own IIFE, gives it its own scope so it doesn't create symbol conflicts with the other inserted modules.

This makes the following assumptions.

1. It assumes that the code from each of the `settingNameX.js` files assigns the appropriate object to `module.exports` like your examples show.  In the real world, you probably want to add a bunch of tests to see if the right thing is assigned to module.exports (proper defensive coding).
2. It assumes that the inserted modules are not assigning conflicting things to the global object.
3. It assumes your own module doesn't need the `module.exports` or can overwrite it at the end after the inserted modules have used it.  If this assumption isn't OK, then you'd have to manually change `module.exports =` to something else that you define in your master module.